# How to nest mocha describes in junit.xml

Tags: node.js, jenkins, junit, mocha.js, jenkins-plugins

I have a series of mocha tests which include nested describes such as

```
describe('Tests.', () => {
  describe('Test Method 1', () => {
    it('should do x', () => {
      // test code
    });

    it('should do y', () => {
      // test code
    });
  });
  describe('Test Method 2', () => {
    it('should do x', () => {
      // test code
    });

    it('should do y', () => {
      // test code
    });
  });
});
```

I'm using mocha-junit-reporter to produce junit.xml which looks like this

```
<testsuite name="Root Suite Tests." failures="0" time="0"> </testsuite>
<testsuite name="Root Suite Tests. Test Method 1" failures="0" time="0">
  <testcase name="should do x" time="0" classname="Tests. Test Method 1 should do x"> 
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="should do y" time="0" classname="Tests. Test Method 1 should do y"> 
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Root Suite Tests. Test Method 1" failures="0" time="0">...</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Root Suite Tests. Test Method 2" failures="0" time="0">
  <testcase name="should do x" time="0" classname="Tests. Test Method 2 should do x"> 
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="should do y" time="0" classname="Tests. Test Method 2 should do y"> 
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Root Suite Tests. Test Method 2" failures="0" time="0">...</testsuite>
```

The options for mocha-junit-reporter are

```
"useFullSuiteTitle": true,
"testCaseSwitchClassnameAndName": true
```

The JUnit.xml when displayed in Jenkins using the Test Results Analyzer plugin displays like this

> Tests
>
> ```
>  Test Method 1 should do x
>
>  Test Method 1 should do y    
>
>  Test Method 2 should do x    
>
>  Test Method 2 should do y
> ```

I would like it to display like this

> Tests
>
> ```
>  Test Method 1 
>
>       should do x
>
>       should do y 
>
>  Test Method 2 
>
>       should do x 
>
>       should do y
> ```

Is this possible? And if it is possible what do I need to do to make it so?

Comment: JUnit does not support nested suites, at least in version 4, so junit.xml propably has the same problem.